# How to pickle a dictionary with models inside?

Tags: python, dictionary, model, pickle, dill

I fitted the transformers model DistillBert on various data and saved each fitted model in a dictionary with

{dataname : fitted DistillBert model}

How can I save this dictionary with pickle? If pickle does not work, how can I make use of dill to save this dictionary and make use of the models inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use pickle out of the box on your own to save model if you are using pytorch. Because `torch.save()` and `torch.load()` takes care of it. `torch.save` function uses Python’s pickle utility for serialization. And you can save the model using this.

In case of Keras/Tensorflow you can use simply `model.save()` instead of using pickle even though Keras models are pickle-able. Models saved like this will be compatible with future versions of Keras and can be used in other platforms.

In any case you can use `dill` to store it like that:

```
import dill
...
...
#class definition of model1's class
...
#class definition of model2's class
...
d = dict(a1=model1, a2=model2)

with open("dillfilename", "wb") as dill_file:
    dill.dump(d , dill_file)
```

Also similarly you can use `dill.load` to load the dill file.

Comment: Does this include dictionaries with models inside? I do not want to save each model individually

Comment: @user16894190 What do you exactly mean by dictionaries with models inside? You will save that model individually with `torch.save`. Then we will find the saved model weights and load it individually with `torch.load()`. If your model is using any other model inside of it, and part of the data flow graph then that will be considered a single model

Comment: As I said in my question: I want to append each model to a dictionary (I do not want xxx individual pickle files for each model) and then pickle this dictionary in order to unpickle it later on and receive all models saved in this dictionary

Comment: @user16894190 Yes you can do that but it is not a good practice and it might be performance wise inefficient.

Comment: and how could I do that without receiving any errors?

Comment: @user16894190 This is so uncommon a scenario. Let me check.